# How do I programmatically capture and replicate Ai path shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I'm using ExtendScript for scripting Adobe Illustrator. I was wondering if there was a sneaky way or a script available to programmatically capture and then replicate a path shape, sort of JavaScript's `.toSource()` equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
main();
function main(){

var doc = app.activeDocument; // get the active doc

var coords = new Array(); // make a new array for the coords of the path
var directions = new Array();

var sel = doc.selection[0];// get first object in selection

if(sel == null) {
    // check if something is slected
    alert ("You need to sevlect a path");
    return;
    }

    var points = sel.pathPoints;// isolate pathpoints
    // loop points
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    // this could be done in one lines
    // just to see whats going on line like
//~      coords.push(new Array(points[i].anchor[0],points[i].anchor[1]));
    var p = points[i]; // the point
    var a = p.anchor; // his anchor
    var px = a[0];// x
    var py = a[1]; // y
    var ldir = p.leftDirection;
    var rdir = p.rightDirection;
    directions.push(new Array(ldir,rdir));
    coords.push(new Array(px,py));// push into new array of array   
  }
var new_path = doc.pathItems.add(); // add a new pathitem

new_path.setEntirePath(coords);// now build the path


    // check if path was closed
if(sel.closed){
    new_path.closed = true;
    }

// set the left and right directions
for(var j = 0; j < new_path.pathPoints.length;j++){

    new_path.pathPoints[j].leftDirection = directions[j][0];
    new_path.pathPoints[j].rightDirection = directions[j][1];    
    }
}
```